# RStudio Beginner: Joining tables

Tags: rstudio

So I am doing a project on trip start and end points for a bike sharing program. I have two .csv files - one with the trips, which shows a start and end station ID (e.g. Start at 1, end at 5). I then have another .csv file which contains the lat/lon coordinates for each station number.

How do I join these together? I basically just want to create a lat and lon column alongside my trip data so it's one .csv file ready to be mapped.

I am completely new to R and programming/data in general so go easy! I realize it's probably super simple. I could do it by hand in excel but I have over 100,000+ trips so it might take a while...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include in the above question, what are the "column headings" aka Variables, for trips.csv and for stations.csv? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using just **Excel** and the **VLOOKUP** function.

You would need your two CSV files in the same spreadsheet but on different tabs.  Your stations would need to be in order of ID (you can order it in Excel if you need to) and then follow the instructions in the video below.

[Example use of VLOOKUP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tk_Mif7040).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step on how to use start and end station ids from one csv, and get the corresponding latitude and longitudes from another.

In technical terms, this shows you how to make use of `merge()` to find commonalities between two data frames:

### Files

Firstly, simple fake data for demonstration purposes:

coordinates.csv:

```
station_id,lat,lon
1,lat1,lon1
2,lat2,lon2
3,lat3,lon3
4,lat4,lon4
```

trips.csv:

```
start,end
1,3
2,4
```

### Import

Start R or rstudio in the same directory containing the csvs.

Then import the csvs into two new data frames `trips` and `coords`.  In R console:

```
> trips = read.csv('trips.csv')
> coords = read.csv('coordinates.csv')
```

### Merges

A first merge can then be used to get `start` station's coordinates:

```
> trip_coords = merge(trips, coords, by.x = "start", by.y = "station_id")
```

- `by.x = "start"` tells R that in the first data set `trips`, the unique id variable is named `start`
- `by.y = "station_id"` tells R that in the second data set `coords`, the unique id variable is named `station_id`
- this is an example of how to merge data frames when the same id variable is named differently in each data set, and you have to explicitly tell R

We check and see `trip_coords` indeed has combined data, having start, end but also latitude and longitude for the station specified by `start`:

```
> head(trip_coords)
  start end  lat  lon
1     1   3 lat1 lon1
2     2   4 lat2 lon2
```

Next, we want the latitude and longitude for `end`. We don't need to make a separate data frame, we can use `merge()` again, and build upon our `trip_coords`:

```
> trip_coords = merge(trip_coords, coords, by.x = "end", by.y = "station_id")
```

Check again:

```
> head(trip_coords)
  end start lat.x lon.x lat.y lon.y
1   3     1  lat1  lon1  lat3  lon3
2   4     2  lat2  lon2  lat4  lon4
```

- the `.x` and `.y` suffixes appear because merge combines two data frames, and our data frame 1 was `trip_coords` which already had a `lat` and `lon`, and data frame 2 `coords` also has `lat` and `lon`. So the `merge()` function needed to help us tell them apart after merge, so
- for data frame 1, aka original `trip_coords`, `lat` and `lon` is automatically renamed to `lat.x` and `lon.x`
- for data frame 2, aka `coords`, has `lat` and `lon` is automatically renamed to `lat.y` and `lon.y`

But now, the default result puts variable `end` first. We may prefer to see the order `start` followed by `end`, so to fix this:

```
> trip_coords = trip_coords[c(2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```

- we re-order and then save the result back into `trip_coords`

We can check the results:

```
> head(trip_coords)
  start end lat.x lon.x lat.y lon.y
1     1   3  lat1  lon1  lat3  lon3
2     2   4  lat2  lon2  lat4  lon4
```

### Export

```
> write.csv(trip_coords, file = "trip_coordinates.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

- saves csv
- where `file =` to set the file path to save to. In this case just `trip_coordinates.csv` so this will appear in the current working dir, where you have the other csvs
- `row.names = FALSE` otherwise by default, the first column is filled with automatic row numbers

You can check the results, for example on Linux, on your command prompt:

```
$ cat trip_coordinates.csv
"","start","end","lat.x","lon.x","lat.y","lon.y"
"1",1,3,"lat1","lon1","lat3","lon3"
"2",2,4,"lat2","lon2","lat4","lon4"
```

So now you have a method for taking trips.csv, getting lat/lon for each of start and end, and outputting a csv again.

### Automation

Remember that with R you can automate, write the exact commands you want to run, save it in a `myscript.R`, so if your source data changes and you wish to re-generate the latest `trip_coordinates.csv` without having to type all those commands again, you have at least two options to run the script

Within R or the R console you see in rstudio:

```
> source('myscript.R')
```

Or, if on the Linux command prompt, use `Rscript` command:

```
$ Rscript myscript.R
```

and the `trip_coordinates.csv` would be automatically generated.

### Further resources

- [How to Use the merge() Function...](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-merge-function-with-data-sets-in-r.navId-812015.html): Good VENN diagrams of the different joins